# Arduino error: 'fseek' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, arduino

For an arduino sketch I have a c header file where I keep all the static methods, let it be 'Utils.h'. Now, in one of the method I am working with `FILE*` pointers and I need to call `fseek` method, but when compiling, Arduino gives me that:

```
error: 'fseek' was not declared in this scope
   fseek(stream, 0, 0);
                     ^
Error compiling.
```

I included `<stdio.h>`, also tried a solution from another similar question

```
#if ARDUINO >= 100
  #include "Arduino.h"
#else
  #include "WProgram.h"
#endif
```

but no success.
How can I use fseek in Arduino, or can I at all?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm more curious as to where you found an implementation of `fopen()`...

Comment: oh..so there isn't one.
I just use an HTTPClient library which returns a FILE*

Comment: I suspect, although I have no proof, that you won't be getting a seekable stream from that library regardless.

Comment: thanks. I guess I have to rethink the program logic then

Comment: What does your program have to do? I'm curious ...

Comment: It's kind of http client in this regard. It calls some web service(WS) methods to accomplish certain tasks, including LED lighting, and answers back with command status and other parameters. The WS is hosted elsewhere.